# Return only a HTTP status code from curl command

Tags: command-line-interface, curl, command

I want to just get a statusCode from **CURL** command response.

When I use this command:

```
curl -I  http://uploadserver.ln/1.mp4
```

I want to just get **200** rather than this long result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 01 Jul 2018 12:47:02 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 1055736
Last-Modified: Sat, 30 Jun 2018 07:58:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5b373821-101bf8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the `-w` parameter to define the format `curl` outputs. To get the status code and nothing else, use something like this:

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The output should look like this:

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://www.google.com
200
```

Note, the `-o` defines that the output for the page will be sent to /dev/null - this way it will only print out the status code and not the page contents.